# Navigationbar changes bartintcolor randomly only on iPhone 4

Tags: objective-c, ios7, navbar

I have a serious problem with an App on iPhone 4 devices running IOS 7. My App has a TabbarController with 5 Tabs each Tab has a NavigationController (and the view a navigationbar). My App is working great on iPhone 5 and even with all devices in the simulator but not with a real iPhone 4.

My goal was that every Tab has its own navigationbar color, so in the viewWillAppear method i made for example this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.102 green:0.129 blue:0.282 alpha:1.0]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

As I mentioned before, it works great except the real iPhone 4. If I switch through the tabs all seems to be working, colors of the navigationbars are correct. But when I open one Tab again (which I already have opened before) the navigationBar is PLAIN WHITE!!!

I am confused why?

Comment: Could you post more code? Also, are you able to get the navigation bar to be plain white at the same point each time?

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you change setTranslucent:YES to setTranslucent:NO?

Comment: nothing changes if i setTranslucent:NO (navbar is WHITE). I found a new fact. This behaviour appears only if I previously selected the MapView Tab and another ViewController with this NavigationBar has already once being opened. Hope this is helpful (in my opinion a video would be the best way to show you this behaviour...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who ran into the same issue... it is a bug and already reported.
See the Apple DEV Forum. It seems that this is only happening if you also use the mapkit.

Comment: So... this seems pretty bad... i have an iPad 2 and it has the exact same problem... what am I gonna do now... what did you do to solve this?

Comment: Try to play with the setTranslucent method... either YES or NO... try it out :) And: Make a bug report ;)

Comment: Well... this is fixed now in iOS 7.0.4. Just downloaded and I don't have this issue anymore. Neither my customer had any issue... I think it´s related to some devices only. I did try translucent, but the barTintColor would still be white...